# Sending email from MAMP Pro

Tags: php, macos, email, mamp, mamp-pro

I just bought MAMP Pro and am using it on a Mac (Sierra).

Despite configuring (and reconfiguring) the options for Postfix in MAMP Pro and the corresponding php.ini, it will not send an email using PHP. It doesn't even seem to create a log file so that I can see what's going wrong.

I've search SO and other solutions, but all seem a bit dated and aren't working for me.

Does anyone have any insight into getting MAMP Pro to send emails on a Mac?

Comment: "I've search SO and other solutions" What makes your situation unique from those questions? I'd prefer to just add my new/updated answer to those questions if I had anything.

Comment: @HPierce They seem out of date and not applicable to the current MacOS or MAMP version, and the solutions do not work.